# Unable to cURL into redis

Tags: curl, redis, ubuntu-20.04

I'm getting a connection refused error on port 9443. redis-server is definitely running, version 7.2.4. I'm not finding any other configuration I need to be setting up. It's not using the docker image. I tried allowing the port ufw, but that doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Here's what `ss -tlnp | grep redis` looks like:

```
LISTEN    0         511              127.0.0.1:6379             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("redis-server",pid=3281773,fd=6))
LISTEN    0         511                  [::1]:6379                [::]:*        users:(("redis-server",pid=3281773,fd=7))
```

So it looks like it's just the redis-cli port.

Here's what my log looks like since starting:

```
3281773:C 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.088 * oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
3281773:C 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.088 * Redis version=7.2.4, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=3281773, just started
3281773:C 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.088 * Configuration loaded
3281773:M 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.089 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
3281773:M 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.090 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
3281773:M 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.091 * Server initialized
3281773:M 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.091 * Loading RDB produced by version 7.2.4
3281773:M 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.091 * RDB age 1 seconds
3281773:M 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.091 * RDB memory usage when created 0.87 Mb
3281773:M 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.091 * Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 1, keys expired: 0.
3281773:M 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.091 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
3281773:M 17 Jan 2024 00:35:56.091 * Ready to accept connections tcp
3281773:M 17 Jan 2024 00:40:42.912 * CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.
```

Comment: What do the logs from redis look like? Does `ss -tlnp | grep redis` (as `root`) show any listening ports?

Comment: @larsks edited to provide that info

Comment: Regular Redis listens only on port 6379. [Redis Enterprise](https://redis.com/comparisons/oss-vs-enterprise/) apparently provides a REST interface and other features available on other ports.